# How to autosize the form window based on screen resolution during run time (Where the size of the window created during design is too large)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, windows

I have created a windows application where the form size is large enough to view.

I want the form to shrink or maximize based on the screen resolution of the display such that the user can view all the controls in a compact way.

I tried the auto size property in the form but that doesn't work. Is there any property in the form which can resolve this issue?

Or do I need to code something else to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the Form.WindowState = Maximized?

Comment: No I didnt.. what doest it do.. can you explain it a little bit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the **WindowState = Maximized** will cause the window to open to the full extents of the screen resolution. It doesn't matter what that value is, it will match it.

[image]

Edit:
From your comments, it sounds like you want what the **AutoSize** property will accomplish. I updated the form to add some controls and set the **AutoSize = True** and the **AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink**. Between these three properties, you should be able to get the form to do exactly what you wish. The one thing to pay attention to is the full extents of your controls within the form. From this picture you can see the form during runtime will resize to fit both text boxes while in the editor, I shrunk the form to hide almost everything. Please also note that in the example below, I set the **WindowState = Normal**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I know this idea.... But the problem is that the windows form looks too big during runtime... I just want it to be compact and precise for the view.... Can this be made ?

Comment: @GowthamRamamoorthy Hmm. You're sort of contradicting your first request then. Do you want the form to match the screen resolution or do you want the form to match the full extents of the controls on the form? Please be a bit more clear.

Comment: @GowthamRamamoorthy I edited to show an example of what I believe you want to accomplish. Pay attention to the extents of your controls. If the form is not as expected, the extents of the controls may not be what you think they are.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the form load event, do this:

```
    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Rectangle resolutionRect = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
        if (this.Width >= resolutionRect.Width || this.Height >= resolutionRect.Height) {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
```